# Servicestack ORMLite update child collection

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I can see you can do stuff like this in ORMLite:

```
var customer =  new Customer {
    Name = "Customer 1",
    PrimaryAddress = new CustomerAddress {
        AddressLine1 = "1 Australia Street",
        Country = "Australia"
    },
    Orders = new[] {
        new Order { LineItem = "Line 1", Qty = 1, Cost = 1.99m },
        new Order { LineItem = "Line 2", Qty = 2, Cost = 2.99m },
    }.ToList(),
};

db.Save(customer, references:true);
```

But what about updating child collections?

How is this done?

To expand on this.

I have a UserAccount class and an Image class internal to UserAccount:

```
public class UserAccount 
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {
        get ;
        set;
    }

    public UserAccount()
    {
        Images = new List<UserImage>();
    }

    public List<UserImage> Images { get; protected set; }

    public UserImage Image { get; set; }

    public class UserImage
    {
        public UserImage()
        {
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public UserImage(string name)
        {
            Value = name;
            Created = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Doing this:

```
var fullImage = new UserAccount.UserImage(newImageUrl);
fullImage.IsDefault = true;
user.Image = fullImage;
db.Update (fullImage);
```

Doesn't work.

Doing this:

```
var fullImage = new UserAccount.UserImage(newImageUrl);
fullImage.IsDefault = true;
user.Images.Add(fullImage);
db.Update (fullImage);
```

Doesn't work...

Also doing the same but having image as a seperate entity with it's own ID and setting reference on the parent class doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the way:

```
var image = new UserImage(newImageUrl);
image.IsDefault = true;
db.Save (image);

var images = user.Images;
images.Add (image);

db.Update (new UserAccount{Id = user.Id, Image = image, Images = images});
```

I hope I am wrong because that is so ugly :/

[UPDATE]

I have it looking like this now which is much nicer:

```
db.UpdateOnly (user, 
    onlyFields: a=> new { a.Image, a.Images}, 
    where: ua => ua.Id == user.Id);
```